# can ROS be installed on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

The ROS wiki has tutorials about installing ROS on Ubuntu 10.10 & 10.04, bu for some certain reasons I need to keep my current Ubuntu 9.10. Does anyone know if there will be problems if I install ROS on Ubuntu 9.10? Or has anyone tried that?

Thanks,
Zhu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9498/can-ros-be-installed-on-ubuntu-9.10?/) by [Zhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/259/zhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that according to [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), that Box Turtle and C Turtle both support Ubuntu 9.10, Karmic Koala. [CTurtle Ubuntu installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu)

That's not to say that you couldn't at least attempt to install Diamondback or latest on 9.10, but you may have a longer road ahead than just the ROS installation guide.  You may have to add additional packages to Ubuntu in order to support the newer dependencies that come with Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1